# OpenAI spinning up convolutional networks with PPO

Tags: reinforcement-learning, open-ai

I am using pytorch version of [PPO](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/algorithms/ppo.html#documentation-pytorch-version) and I have image input that I need to process with convolutional neural networks, are there any examples on how to set up the network? I know that [stable baselines](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/)  support this to some extend, but I had better performance with spinning up so I would prefer to keep using these.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a tutorial on using OpenAI Spinning Up in a image-based PyBullet + Gym environment [here](https://www.etedal.net/2020/04/pybullet-panda_3.html)

In order to be able to use spinup for an image-based environment I had to fork it [here](https://github.com/mahyaret/spinningup) and add CNN to PPO's core.py